# Netbeans can't auto deploy project java?

Tags: java, netbeans

My netbeans is version 7.3.1.
I code web java, but when I save java class project not auto deploy, I always deploy project by hand.
What happends with my netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project and click on **Properties**. And check for **Run** configurations.

Here's a snap of what I'm working on and everything gets deployed for me on save.

[image]